# Where to locate "et-custom-css" in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress page http://alterknit.staging.wpengine.com/drop-off where some of the css classes falls under `<style type="text/css" id="et-custom-css">`. It also has a comment `/*  - - - - - -  Additional page info - - - - - - - */` at top of it. When I click edit page, I am unable to see these CSS. I am sure it is not in style.css. I am new to Wordpress and I have no idea where these styles reside. Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: This sounds like it's probably in your Wordpress admin under Appearance -> Custom CSS. Alternatively, it could be in your theme's functions.php.

Comment: Ok let me check it.

Comment: I just saw the image you added. It could also be as a result of a custom background being added in Appearance -> Customizer

Comment: @TimMalone I do not find Custom CSS in Appearance!

Comment: @TimMalone No customizer option either :(

Comment: Theme documentation is your best bet then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress is wonderfully dynamic and there are lots of ways to achieve lots of things.

In your case, it looks like the CSS is added by the theme. The Vertex theme is from Elegant Themes and you should review their support documentation.

http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/documentation/advanced-design-settings/.

Elegant Themes have a support function and knowledgebase to guide you.

Get to know the WordPress codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/ and functions like [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/). You'll be able to achieve more and be more efficient with your output.

Comment: Please be more specific please!

Comment: Read the content on the link. It shows you where the custom css has been added and where you can edit it.